# React. Как получить размеры элемента

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Есть главный компонент. Он включает в себя еще одни компонент (блок с тремя кнопками). Как мне в главном компоненте получить размеры блока который содержит кнопки.

Получается App.js => buttons.js (в разных файлах)

Comment: Через ref тащить тот и дальше уже по dom'у лазить руками?